# HTACCESS, ¿Cómo crear urls amigables para un subdominio?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, reescritura-url

Tengo un inconveniente con el **`.htaccees`**. Creé un subdominio (**`tienda.gsdeveloper.com.ar`**) el cual se redirecciona a la carpeta (**`/clientes/tienda/`**). EL problema se me generó con las urls del menú porque cuando quiero ir a el link "products" me envía a **`https://tienda.gsdeveloper.com.ar/products`** pero no funciona.

Dejo el código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} tienda.gsdeveloper.com.ar [NC]

RewriteRule ^home/?$    /clientes/tienda/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^about/?$    /clientes/tienda/quienes.php [L]
RewriteRule ^products/?$    /clientes/tienda/productos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact/?$    /clientes/tienda/contacto.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ingresar/?$    /clientes/tienda/login.php [L]
```

Aguardo su colaboración. Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Para qué es esta regla `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [L,NC,QSA]`? Aplica para cualquier ruta, no tiene sustitución y no permite evaluar la reglas posteriores.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Ya edité esa línea. La había tomado de un tutorial pero como has visto, mi manejo de htaccess es muy escaso. De todos modos, se entiende de mi consulta?

Comment: De hecho, sin esa línea ¿cuál es el resultado?.

Answer (score 1):

un posible error común: reiniciaste el servidor y limpiaste el cache de tu navegador?

protip: cuando estas probando configuraciones de servidores web, intenta usar alguna herramienta específica que asegure que la página siempre es descargada de nuevo. Muchos navegadores reusan los datos previamente descargados la última vez que accediste al mismo sitio. Por ejemplo, intenta acceder a tu página usando siempre navegación privada ya que al cerrar el navegador los datos siempre son eliminados, lo que fuerza al navegador volver a descargar la página cada vez. O más recomendable, hacer uso completo de las herramientas devtools de tu navegador de preferencia.

Comment: Gracias por tu colaboración. El archivo está funcionando bien en el servidor con las urls amigables. Ahora quise modificar la url de l subdominio (como lo planteo en el post) y me devuelve la ruta completa ( https://gsdeveloper.com.ar/clientes/tienda/products) y lo que quiero es que me lo reemplace por esto: https://tienda.gsdeveloper.com.ar/products. No quiero mostrar la ruta real de la carpeta. Se entiende? Gracias.